# Azure Custom Connector for 3rd Party API with Oauth 2.0 access token

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get data from a 3rd party API into an Azure SQL DB using Azure Data Factory with out using SSIS.

This lead me down a rabbit hole and I have been searching for 3 days now and cannot find a solution.I must be missing something.

I have tried using Azure Data Factory and the copy data controls.
I then tried using power apps and cant find anything that helps.
I then tried custom connector, from scrach, from postman and from OpenAPI

I cannot get any of it to work!

I really thought this would be easier than this?

I have read almost all of the standard MicroSoft documentation and none of it helps with my specific scenario.

I have a third party web site that I get an authorisation token from using a username and password with grant-type=password
Using this token I then get JSON data from the site.

I want to get this data into my SQL DB in Azure.

Thats it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

PS:Next step is the same thing but API returns XML, rabbit hole 2...

Comment: So the main process you want to do is fetching json data from 3rd API by Oauth2.0 password flow without user interaction . Once json data fetched , you will use Azure Data factory to import json data into Azure SQL ?

Comment: @StanleyGong Yes Stanley. That basically sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal) that import data from Azure Storage to Azure SQL Database using pipeline.

I think this guide will be helpful for you. Before you follow this guide to meet your requirement, you should import your JSON data from 3rd party API first. So you can use [Azure logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) to finish this process quickly.

I have finished this process , it is easy and just few steps : 
[image]
 1. Getting access token from 3rd party identity provider(here I use Azure AD as identity provider, just for demo) using http request action:
[image]
 2. Generally , we can get an access token from step1 , use this auth info to call your 3rd API to fetch json data using http request action directly:
[image] 
The API I am using is a sample demo one, just reply a json as :

```
{
    "name": "stan",
    "id": "123"
}
```

3. Using create blob action to create a blob file with the json content from previous step (you should create a storage account with a blob container first , so that you can store files, here I name the json file with guid)
   [image]

Run this logic App you can see that a json file has been created in Azure storage account with the json data from API :
[image]

So the steps left , you can just refer to the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal) to import data to your SQL, just selecting json as resource format in Configure source section.
If you have anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know. Hope it helps : )

Comment: Hi, is this solution helpful ?